# Git push --force so that remote master discards bad commits?

Tags: git, github

I made some bad commits to a project hosted on github. I removed the commits with github's bfg tool and then pushed to github and git cloned the project on the various local machines that I use. Everything is normal between my local machines and github.

However, I deploy to a remote that still contains the bad commits. When I do:

```
git push remote master
```

I get this error:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@remote:blah/blah.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I do:

```
git push --force remote master
```

Everything proceeds as expected; however, I have to do that each time. Is there a way to tell git to overwrite master on the remote so that it discards the bad commits without cloning?

Comment: Did you try to do what the error suggests and run `git pull ...`? The error means that you have something new on the remote side what you don't have locally.

Comment: The problem is that the "new" commits on the remote side are bad and need to be discarded. I don't want them merged.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have something new on the remote side what you don't have locally and according to your comment:

> The problem is that the "new" commits on the remote side are bad and need to be discarded. I don't want them merged.

In this case `--force` is the only way to overwrite "bad" commits.

But it also means you are using wrong git workflow. You should never get these "bad" commits on master if you do it like this:

- Create a new branch for each new feature and do the development there, never commit directly to the `master` branch
- Once feature is done - review the change, if it is good - merge it to master, if not - discard it (just don't merge)

Answer (score -1):

If you are just adding new commits to your remote repository, you can `git push remote master` to update your remote repo with your local new commits. However, if you are not just adding new commits but **deleting** or **updating** some of them, you are not allowed to `git push`. In this case you need to `git push --force remote master` to replace (instead of update) your remote commit history with your local one.